# О "ягодной" этимологии

Tags: этимология, мифология

Прочитал предыдущий вопрос о смерти. В нем упоминается мифическая речка Смородина, которая, как я понимаю, является славянским аналогом Стикса. Через речку Смородину перекинут Калинов мост. Очень интересно, что топонимика этих мифических объектов связана с ягодами: смородиной и калиной. Но почему?
В вопросе говорилось о плохом запахе, который связывали со смертью. Но смородина пахнет очень хорошо, ее даже добавляют в чай для аромата. Калина тоже неприятным запахом не отличается и, в отличие от рябины, по-моему, не считалась погребальным растением.
Откуда же взялась эта "ягодная" этимология?

Answer (score 2):

Есть версия, что "смрад" означал изначально сильный, удушливый запах. У Фасмера можно прочитать, что "смородина" происходит от "смород/смрад". Что касается Калинова моста, то я нашел две версии: а) Калинов — это "раскаленный" (от слова "калить"), "огненный" и б) калина активно использовалась во всяких обрядах, была даже погребальным растением.

Comment: Калинов мост это мост царя Калина , а не "раскалённый мост" . Царь Калин известен и в других сюжетах без всякого моста . Не фантазируйте , батенька !

Answer (score 2):

Где-то читала, что название реки Смородины могло происходить от "мор", "морок", "мрак", а ягода смородина - либо от "смрад", как уже было сказано, либо от "сама родит". Не ручаюсь за достоверность этих сведений, так как давно забыла где я это читала или слышала, но всё равно есть вариант что этимологии этих слов не так близко связаны друг с другом.

Интересно послушать, какие ещё есть версии.

Comment: А Калинов мост?

Comment: Я  встречал  версию,  что  это  реально  существовавшие  или  даже  и  ныне  существующие  топонимы.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki: про Калинов мост, к сожалению, ничего не читала. :)

Answer (score 1):

Это называется этимологией от фонаря, что первое в голову придет, знакомые части слов увидели и давай раскручивать...Фасмер придумал. Технологию. Подгон чистой воды. Вообще- смородина курант, в большей части Европы. А что такое куранты-да часы на башне, на которые все смотрят. Время бежит, течет, смотрят -сравнивают.
А что такое смородинка, воняет разве? она благоухает, ее в соления кладут: грибочки, огурчики, в водочку добавляют, в чаек.
а на что ягода похожа, она ж не черная,бурая,  смотри--родинка.Детишкам сравнение в радость. взрослым проблема--догадаться.

Comment: А вот вам нормальная история. Вся Европа была славянской, это их оттуда выгнали, не без помощи Священной римской империи. И когда потом монахам-путешественникам объясняли русские названия , то часто тупо...сравнивали, смотри у вас часы, а у нас смородина.

Comment: Васмер "забыл" про остальные названия смородины на других языках, в частности, в латыни, бесовский дух, все потому, что из нее бражку делали..и с рябиной таж история-lijsterbes. РУЯНСКАЯ ягода--медвежья.Смородина - Винная ягода и в названиях отразилось, и гроздь и вино. А у монахов запретка на пьянку--отсюда и легенды.